# Comment flag declined twice though it no longer applies to current version of question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, declined-flags, comment-flags

Referece [Attribute Routing ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55614820/attribute-routing-asp-net-core#comment97923431_55614820)

When the question was originally asked, the incorrect tags were used.

This of course attracted comments pertaining to the version provided in the tags.

The question was updated to the correct version and I proceeded to remove a series of comments that no longer applied to the question in its current state.

All other flags we helpful but the linked comment's "no longer needed" flag was declined.

I flagged again, this time including a specific explanation as to why the comment was no longer needed.

> I originally flagged this comment as no longer needed and it was declined. This outdated comment applies to a previous version of the framework and will be misleading to future readers.

It was quickly declined again.

What should I have done differently in this situation seeing as the flag was declined twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declined flags were handled by a different moderator than the original comments.

It's not at all clear based solely on the content of the flagged comment...

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

...that it is "no longer needed." When you flagged again, you put a moderator in the position of moderating that comment based on technical accuracy and, generally speaking, moderators don't get involved in technical disputes.

It took me awhile to piece this all together from the post history.  Perhaps I'll recommend some changes to the dashboards to make sussing out these things easier.

Comment: In future how would you suggest I approach *technical* comments like this to avoid putting mods in this situation?

Comment: Seriously, a comment on technical expertise? Did we really upgraded them to first class citizens? I was under the impression that the default was to delete comments unless there were clear indications that there's an ongoing conversation. BTW, if the comment is an answer, it should have been posted as an answer to the question.

Comment: @Braiam: I already deleted the comment, on the grounds that it has become a distraction.

Answer (score 3):

I handled these two flags. [Robert already adequately summarized why I declined the first flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382737/366904). It was not at all obvious from reading the comment why you thought it was "no longer needed". Specifically, it looked like a reasonable suggestion of code to try. There was no compelling reason to delete it.

I do see a fair number of "no longer needed" flags on comments that make suggestions because *one* flagger tried it and couldn't get it to work for them. That's…not a compelling reason for me to delete an apparently relevant comment. Flags aren't a workaround for the lack of a downvote button on comments. It's entirely possible that the person just failed to use the suggested code correctly; the suggestion may still have value to others in the future.

Your second attempt at flagging did nothing to clarify matters for me. In fact, it made things worse. I now felt like I was justified in declaring your "no longer needed" assessment incorrect. You said:

> I originally flagged this comment as no longer needed and it was declined. This outdated comment applies to a previous version of the framework and will be misleading to future readers.

I knew the first sentence to be a fact, of course. The sticking point was the second sentence. There were two issues:

1. One, Robert has already called out: your flag put a moderator in the position of trying to judge technical accuracy/relevance. I'm not qualified to do that when it comes to web-based technologies, and I'm going to err on the side of caution every time. In general, you should not flag comments for moderator attention because they are *wrong* or *incorrect*. See above: flags are not workarounds for the lack of a downvote button on comments.
2. More importantly, **you claimed that the comment was "outdated" because it "applies to a previous version of the framework". In the world of programming, things change rapidly. That does not, however, mean that we should go around deleting all the information related to old versions. Another thing that happens frequently in the world of programming is that people *use* older versions. We should not make it more difficult for them to be able to find help on using those older versions.** You furthermore claimed that, because the comment applied to an older version of the framework, it would "be misleading to future readers". I say pish-posh to that. We don't dumb down and remove content because it might be misleading to someone who doesn't pay attention or know what they're doing. Maybe I have too much faith in the average programmer, but I don't think a comment like this is going to seriously confuse anyone.

*Now* I see that you misphrased your second flag. Instead of saying that the comment is outdated because it applies to a previous version of the *framework*, you apparently meant to say that it applies to a previous version of the *question*. And *that*, of course, would be confusing to future visitors. It is a compelling reason to remove the comment as obsolete.

All of this to say: ***words matter***. Your flag message needs to be *precise* and *correct*; otherwise, it is subject to being misinterpreted.

That a comment applies to a previous version of *a framework* is **not** a reason to delete it. That a comment applies to a previous version of *the question* **is** a reason to delete it. You gave me invalid information, and I declined the flag according to my incorrect understanding.